# HTTP Authentication headers with no "realm"

Tags: python, python-2.7, http-headers, urllib2, urllib

The following code works but gives no output even though there is a file instance lying behind **response**

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = 'id'
password = "Password"
url = "http://abc.def.ghij:3080"

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# retrieve the result
response = urllib2.urlopen("http://abc.def.ghij:3080")
print response.read()
print response.headers
```

header response:

```
    Cache-Control: private

Content-Length: 0

Location: /index.epx

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5

X-AspNet-Version: 4.19

Persistent-Auth: true

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Thu, 04 Jul 2013 15:30:03 GMT

Connection: close
```

but `print response.read` doesnt give any content :O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

The problem is that your webserver is requesting NTLM authentication, so it wont accept BasicAuth. Use NTML authentication while sending request or change your webserver config to allow Basic authentication.

Dont use BasicAuth because it sends user/pwd in plaintext over the network. Minimum safe is DigestAuth or NTLM or GSSNegotiate auth.

Comment: Basic auth is acceptable over a secure connection (SSL/TLS), but I agree that digest is better. I'd still keep Digest over a secure connection, however, as it relies on MD5 which has several demonstrated flaws. As an aside, I gather [Microsoft don't recommend NTLM any more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236715.aspx). The best option from a security point of view is probably client-side certificates for authentication, but that can be fiddly for users.

Comment: @Webmaster at www.dekh i implemented as per u r suggestion its working  but i have wierd problem in here...Please look at the edited question !!